# Average of CASE WHEN field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I get the average of the column TotalTeamMembership?

```
SELECT Player,
CASE WHEN Basketball = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
CASE WHEN Baseball = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
CASE WHEN Football = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TotalTeamMembership
FROM PlayerMembership;
```

This is what I currently get:

[image: Progress]

This is what I need:

[image: Goal]

Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AVG()`:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN Basketball = '' THEN 0.0 ELSE 1 END + 
           CASE WHEN Baseball = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
           CASE WHEN Football = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
           ) AS avg_TotalTeamMembership
FROM PlayerMembership;
```

Comment: @APH . . . A conversion is not necessary, just a decimal point.  The question was not originally tagged with SQL Server.

Comment: I see now that I wasn't wrapping everything in the parenthesis. Changing it to 0.0 float also improved the results. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AVG`aggregate function:

```
SELECT AVG(TotalTeamMembership)
FROM (SELECT Player,
       CASE WHEN Basketball = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
       CASE WHEN Baseball = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
       CASE WHEN Football = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TotalTeamMembership
      FROM PlayerMembership) s;
```